# How to fix infinite loop in guess a number function?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm working on a guess a number function where the user thinks of a random integer and the computer generates a guess. If the user's number is higher, they type + and if it's lower they type -
I'm having trouble with this, when I run the code it goes into an infinite loop. I also need to print the computer's initial guess but when I put it above the loop the code wouldn't run.

```
 def guess_a_number():
   lower = 0
   higher = 100
   num = randint(lower, higher)
   x = input("Higher(+), lower(-), or correct(y)?")

   while x != "y":
     if x == "+":
       lower += 1
       print(num)
     elif x == "-":
       higher = higher - 1
       print(num)
   print("yay :D")
   print(num)
```

Comment: If you're only inc/decrementing by 1 each time, your program is going to take a long time to guess the number - imagine if rand int is 2 and the users number is 97. A suggestion I would have is to inc/decrement by a random integer value which has a ceiling of (higher - num) - this is similar to how we would update a guess on a number as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop body never changes `x`, so the condition will either never be true, or always be true.

You need to prompt *again* for `x` inside the loop.

You could just use an infinite loop and `break` on `'y'`.

```
def guess_a_number():
  lower, higher = 0, 100

  while True:
    num = randint(lower, higher)
    print(f"Is it {num}?")
    x = input("Higher(+), lower(-), or correct(y)?")

    if x == 'y':
      print('Yay!')
      break

    if x == '+': lower = num + 1
    elif x == '-': higher = num - 1
```

You also want to use the number the computer "guesses" to set your bounds, rather than just incrementing or decrementing them. If it prompts with 8 and you say lower, on your first try it could try 90 next, and that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thank you so much that makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Feel free to accept whichever answer you feel best answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
while x != "y":
```

You only declared `x` once, so `x` never changes again, so the while loop never breaks.

So depending on what you want to accomplish, inorder to break out of the while loop, you either have to:

- Update the variable `x` so the condition `x != "y"` becomes `False`
- Check for any other condition

Comment: The variable `x` comes from user input, so personally I don't think it makes sense to update it in this case. However the second suggestion seems at least valid to me.

Comment: If i understand correctly, the computer is supposed to ask the user if the random generated number is the same as or close to the number that the user thought of, So it makes sense to keep asking the user how close the number is or if it is correct using `x = input()` But the program never asks for any input so the while loop gets stuck. If im wrong then i would like to get corrected :)